# GStreamer 1.18.4 undefined symbol gst_rtcp_buffer_add_packet on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gstreamer, meson-build

I'm working on a custom GStreamer plugin. Initially, I developed in on a macOS machine and it works fine there. However, when I compile the plugin on an Ubuntu 20.04 machine, I get a run-time error when I try to inspect the elements in the plugin like this:

`gst-inspect-1.0 lib/umake/gcc-9.3/x86_64/release/libgstscream.so`

The error:

> ```
> (gst-inspect-1.0:617845): GStreamer-WARNING **: 11:07:55.188:
> Failed to load plugin
> 'lib/umake/gcc-9.3/x86_64/release/libgstscream.so':
> lib/umake/gcc-9.3/x86_64/release/libgstscream.so: undefined symbol:
> gst_rtcp_buffer_add_packet Could not load plugin file: Opening module
> failed: lib/umake/gcc-9.3/x86_64/release/libgstscream.so: undefined
> symbol: gst_rtcp_buffer_add_packet
> ```

I installed GStreamer 1.18.4 using [gst-build](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-build) on Ubuntu and also tried re-installing everything.

I don't understand why the symbol `gst_rtcp_buffer_add_packet` seems to be undefined. This method is in gst-plugins-base which is installed by default using the meson build [configuration](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-build/blob/master/meson.build) in gst-build. Is there anything I'm missing?

Here are also the shared object dependencies from `ldd -r lib/umake/gcc-9.3/x86_64/release/libgstscream.so`:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe1f5d2000)
libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 => /opt/gstreamer_1_18_4/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f7ba6616000)
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f7ba659f000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f7ba6476000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f7ba6453000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f7ba6272000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f7ba6123000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f7ba6106000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7ba5f14000)
libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f7ba5f0e000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f7ba5f08000)
libffi.so.7 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7 (0x00007f7ba5efc000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f7ba5e87000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7ba6786000)
undefined symbol: gst_rtcp_buffer_add_packet    (lib/umake/gcc-9.3/x86_64/release/libgstscream.so)
undefined symbol: gst_rtcp_packet_fb_get_media_ssrc (lib/umake/gcc-9.3/x86_64/release/libgstscream.so)
undefined symbol: gst_rtcp_buffer_unmap (lib/umake/gcc-9.3/x86_64/release/libgstscream.so)
undefined symbol: gst_rtcp_packet_fb_set_media_ssrc (lib/umake/gcc-9.3/x86_64/release/libgstscream.so)
undefined symbol: gst_rtcp_packet_get_type  (lib/umake/gcc-9.3/x86_64/release/libgstscream.so)
undefined symbol: gst_rtcp_packet_fb_get_fci_length (lib/umake/gcc-9.3/x86_64/release/libgstscream.so)
undefined symbol: gst_rtcp_buffer_map   (lib/umake/gcc-9.3/x86_64/release/libgstscream.so)
undefined symbol: gst_rtcp_packet_fb_set_fci_length (lib/umake/gcc-9.3/x86_64/release/libgstscream.so)
undefined symbol: gst_rtcp_packet_fb_get_fci    (lib/umake/gcc-9.3/x86_64/release/libgstscream.so)
undefined symbol: gst_rtcp_packet_move_to_next  (lib/umake/gcc-9.3/x86_64/release/libgstscream.so)
undefined symbol: gst_rtcp_buffer_get_first_packet  (lib/umake/gcc-9.3/x86_64/release/libgstscream.so)
```

EDIT: I also added the output of: `GST_REGISTRY=/tmp GST_DEBUG=4 GST_DEBUG_FILE=gstreamer.log gst-inspect-1.0 lib/umake/gcc-9.3/x86_64/release/libgstscream.so` [here](https://pastebin.com/nk7u8Csj). I couldn't detect anything unusual here though.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the symbols could not be found because the RTP dependency was missing in my CMakelists.txt file. The plugin elements can be found now after adding the component Rtp.

`find_package( GStreamer MODULE REQUIRED COMPONENTS Video Audio Rtp )`